# Orthogonal $*$-homomorphisms satisfy $(\phi+\psi)_*=\phi_*+\psi_*$?

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A,B$ be $C^*$ algebras and $\phi, \psi : A\to B$ be *-homomorphisms. We say that they are mutually orthogonal if for all $x,y\in A$ we have $\phi(x) \psi(y)=0$.

It can be shown then that $\phi +\psi$ is also a $*$-homomorphism and if $A, B$ are unital then $K_0(\phi+ \psi)=K_0(\phi)+K_0(\psi)$. The proof using the standard picture of $K_0$ in the unital case and can be found in the book "An introduction to K-theory of C* algebras", page 44.

My question is if this result holds also in the non-unital case? 
If not, I would like to get a counterexample. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Yes, K-theory is additive, always.

For functors from the category of $C^*$-algebras into categories enriched over abelian groups it holds:

> 1. Split exactness implies additivity on objects.

Use herefore that direct sums are particular split exact sequences, and
that split exact sequences with split in categories enriched over abelian groups are direct sums.

> 2. Additive on objects is equivalent to additivity on morphisms.

Use herefore that a pair of parallel $*$-homomorphisms is orthogonal
if and only if the pair admits a lift **from** the direct sum along "its" embeddings.

K-theory is split exact and so the claim follows from the general argumentation above.